# what are benefits of URL rewriting?

Tags: seo, url-rewriting, meta-tags

URL rewriting has become quite popular, but I think it only adds more complexity to the Web.  Old fashioned URL's are often called "dirty URLs", so I'll use that term.

It is argued that with rewriting it makes the URL more "discoverable" but how is it more discoverable with this URL

```
www.magic.com/date/2010/02/02
```

than this URL?

```
www.magic.com/date=2010-02-02
```

I believe people would discover more with the old fashioned URL than the rewrite URL.

With the good old fashioned URL, using ampersands and equal signs, you are actually telling the search engines how they relate to each other.  With slashes you can't.  They don't know that `/2010/02/02` is actually a date or how the numbers relate to the `/date/`.  It merely assumes that it's a different directory with different data.  With `date=2010-02-02` I believe it'll allow search engines to figure out how they relate to each other.

Dirty URLs can easily be shortened with URL shortener services, but everyone copies a URL and pastes it; they don't write it.  It's much simpler if they write down a dirty URL that's well laid out. A URL like `goo.gl/8aPtuI` seems more cognitively difficult than `generic.com/awesome`.

I read an argument that search engines stop at URLs that look dynamically generated, but I am skeptical.  Virtually all websites are dynamically created, so why would they stop there?

I'd also think that dirty URL's can be meta-rich if you do it right.

```
www.generic.com/rate=5&name=Allen&sex=m
```

and it's much easier for engines to see how they are related than doing this,

```
www.generic/com/rate/5/name/Allen/sex/m.
```

What are the real advantages?

Comment: This is arguable: **and it's much easier for engines to see how they are related than doing this**. The "engine" receives the same input, as the webserver (usually) handles the rewriting.

Comment: And I doubt Google "reads" the parameters and processes them in some way, so I don't think Google cares.

Comment: Take this example: www.buy.com/product.aspx?id=321654 compared to www.buy.com/books/computer-science/what-are-the-benefits-of-url-rewriting

Comment: @Mike of course, that would be bad URL but you can make it clear like www.buy.com/book?title=what-are-the-benefits and people can easily add category/author/price pairs to the URL to narrow down.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't so much call it "URL rewriting" so much as "having a sane URL schema". There is a good and bad place for everything.

In the example you give, you are absolutely correct; you have an unordered set of 'parameters' as it were, and the key=value&key2=value2&... syntax is excellent for that.

However with the date example you give, there is a nice **hierarchical structure**. So for example if your site had a monthly listing, you could do `www.magic.com/date/2010/02` for an index page with choice of days, or a yearly listing you could do `www.magic.com/date/2010` for an index of months (and maybe a sidebar with days), and `www.magic.com/date` for an index of years and/or something similar.

It all comes down to what is elegant. Unnecessary URL rewriting (you gave a perfect example) can be as inelegant as a path shoved into key=value query. And only savvy users will bother manually rewriting the URL.

As some other answers point out though, one should take care not to leak internals. For example it is very bad practice to do /mypage.ext?internalThing=blah&... because then everyone knows you're using ext. You should not show the extension of your script. Let's say you want to change mypage.php to mypage.py or something; then (as other answers suggest) this will confuse search engines. This is a separate concern than URL rewriting though; for example it would be just as bad to do /mypage.ext/category. It is probably just a correlation that the people who aren't aware of URL rewriting also aren't aware that /mypage.ext?... links are bad practice.

On the other hand, URL rewriting can require integration with the web server, which may be time better spent on other things.

Comment: Thanks for excellent explanation. I thought the extension doesn't matter - you can make any webpage work with Apache module extensions - you can change a php file to be executed with your preference of extension?

Answer (score 3):

When I was learning about URL rewriting, I found some good articles

[An Overview of URL Rewriting and Its Benefits](http://ezinearticles.com/?An-Overview-of-URL-Rewriting-and-Its-Benefits&id=2507988)

[URL rewriting - benefits and implications](http://www.meloncreative.co.uk/blog/url-rewriting-benefits-and-implications.html)

Also:

1. SEO friendly. If re re engineer the site lets say from asp to aspx then we can keep the same extension but use different
   technology, so old site rating and ranking remains the same
2. Powers the developers for rapid development of web applications or websites. Lets say we have content pages that we manage from CMS and based on them we show in front end, in earlier days we have to create pages at front end but using the URL rewriting we create single page at front end and use URL re writing to inter prate as n different pages
3. Security: It will make site more secure as malicious user will not be able to get to know the structure of the application
4. We avoid the query-string and use URL rewriting to pass on data among various page calls

Comment: thanks, didn't realize URL rewriting can discourage hotlinking.

Comment: netrox: I don't think highly of the first article at all, and it is slightly misleading. URL-rewriting has no effect whatsoever on hotlinking, unless you are periodically changing your URL, in which case you're also periodically destroying your search engine rankings. To deal with hotlinking, you detect the HTTP referrer from the user-agent and block the site.

Answer (score 0):

One good opinion I like:

> "I think the prime reasons are
>   **usability** and **search engine
>   optimization**. From the SEO
>   perspective, I think you can get
>   keywords into the URL rather than
>   ID#'s. For your users, it is easier to
>   navigat a site with:
>
> mysite.com/products/tools/hammers/stanley
>
> than:
>
> mysite.com/products.aspx?id=43245&cat=33&subcat=867&manfuacturer=854
>
> The user can just take off sections of
>   the URL to navigate up a level. I am
>   sure there are a lot of other goof
>   reasons, but those are some main
>   ones."

And from **security** point of view:

> It will make site more
>   secure as malicious user will not be
>   able to get to know the structure of
>   the application

And a quote from [Google Blog](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2006/10/update-to-our-webmaster-guidelines.html):

> Keep in mind, however, that dynamic
>   URLs with a large number of parameters
>   may be problematic for search engine
>   crawlers in general, so *rewriting
>   dynamic URLs into user-friendly
>   versions is always a good practice*
>   when that option is available to you.
>   If you can, keeping the number of URL
>   parameters to one or two may make it
>   more likely that search engines will
>   crawl your dynamic urls.

Comment: The claim "I think you can get keywords into the URL rather than ID#s" seems rather unfounded, as you could just have /products?id=43245, or /products?cat=tools&subcat=hammers&manufacturer=stanley

Comment: "mysite.com/products.aspx?id=43245&cat=33&subcat=867&manfuacturer=854" is just as bad as url rewriting IMO. If I were the make it, I'd do like this: mysite.com/products?product=Ruffles&manufacturer=Lays